# Feature map of convolutional-neural-network and total number of parameters

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Suppose i have an **RGB** image with dimension 125 * 125 and i use 10 filters with 5 * 5 dimension and stride =3 so what is feature map for this layer ? and what is the total number of parameters
my guess for feature map: 10*((125-5)/3)+1 = (41 * 41 * 10)(no of filters) but what is the difference between RGB image or Greyscale image  so for RGB image it should be 41 * 41 * 30 ( no of filters * no of channels of input image)?
and for total number of parameters:5 * 5 * 3 * 10=750 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No of feature maps = no of filters and the size of each feature map would be 41 * 41(you correctly calculated it, if the padding is zero). So, in the case above you would have 10 feature maps of size 41 * 41 independent of rgb or greyscale, if you have 10 filters.

For rgb vs greyscale, think about channels as feature maps for input layer and a filter gets applied on all feature map at once. If you have an input rgb image with 5 * 5 filter size, it is actually a filter of size 5 * 5 * 3(no. of channels). So, independent of rgb or greyscale if you apply 10 filters of 5*5 on an image of size 125 * 125 with stride 3, you will always get out 10 feature maps of 41 * 41.

Whenever you define a filter, it is defined as x * y but the z is always equal to 'no of channels on which you have applied the conv' for 2d convolutions. That way total no of parameters for each filter would be x * y * n_channels + 1 (additional 1 is for the constant)

In your case of 10 filters, for rgb image, each filter is of size 5 * 5 * 3. So, total parameters for rgb= 10 * (5 * 5 * 3 + 1). And for greyscale each filter is 5 * 5 * 1. So, total parameters for greyscale =10 * (5 * 5 * 1 + 1)

Comment: I think you forgot to add the parameters from the added bias terms. So it would become `10 * (5 * 5 * 3 + 1)` :)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned ignoring the constant but it is better to include it. I have made the edits. Thanks! :)

Comment: so every filter applied 3 times for 3 channels and i have 10 filters so its 30 layers of size 41*41 or after applying every filter with 3 channels i add the pixels value for 3 layers and i get 1 layer for every filter with 3 channels so the answer is 41*41*10 ?

Comment: 1 filter is applied on all the image channels at the same time, so if you have 10 filters you will get an output of 41*41*10, independent of how many channels your input has.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** I have a [well-recieved post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80436/understanding-how-convolutional-layers-work/80444#80444) on the intuition on how CNNs work on Data Science Stack Exchange. Do check it out as well.

You are right about the shape of the feature maps, with the given stride.

The total number of parameters in CNN is given by -

```
Params = (n*m*l+1)*k

where, l = number of input feature maps / image channels, 
       k = number of output feature maps / # of filters, 
       n*m = filter dimensions

Important! - The +1 in the formula is because each of the output feature
maps have a bias term added, which is also a trainable parameter. So, don't
forget to add that!
```

So for your case is, number of trainable params: `((5*5*3+1)*10) = 760`

And, for a greyscale it is: `((5*5*1+1)*10) = 260`

---

A very good visualization that I find intuitive to show how filters work to create feature maps is this.

[image]

The `input feature maps` are the same as the number of channels of the input image if it's the first CNN layer. Since CNNs are usually stacked, the output channels of previous CNNs are called `input feature maps` to the current CNN layer.

[image]